# Request facebook permissions each and every time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed an app which requests permission from the user to access their basic details.  Once they have accepted the request permission dialog box, it gets entered into their facebook settings to allow my app to access their basic details.  For example, after the first time, my app will not show them the request permissions dialog box because it has been saved in the users facebook settings.

Is it possible to stop this from happening and ask for their permission each and every time, without the settings getting saved into the users settings section of facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible,

After the user allowed you app, Facebook add it to the user's applications.

Then it's there and the user doesn't have to approve it anymore, whe you ask for permissions again, Facebook sees that it was already approved and skip the permissions dialog. The only way to see this dialog again, is for the user to remove the app permissions in its settings. So next time he will have to accept it again.

Anyway why would you like to show this permissions dialog again , it's one of the biggest barriers for users to use your application (users do not like it, and a lot of them stop when they see this dialog and never come back). Actually it's stated in facebook doc somewhere that the more permissions you ask, the less users will accept and use your app ...

Comment: The reason why I wanted to do this was to give the user the feeling of more security and also give them the feeling of control, i.e. only if they check an option in my application, permissions should be asked for each and every time, if the checkbox is not checked, it should do the default, i.e. save the permissions and only ask once.

Comment: @oshirowanen Yep I don't think that is possible ... the only way to show the permissions dialog again is to change the list of permissions you ask, and even with that it only shows the one you added to the list any facebook guy here knows a way ?

Comment: you can just simulate the dialog permissions, making your own icons and text, or just put them on the side to note that "we are accessing your data again". anyway, facebook privacy settings already show when was the last time an app accessed your info.

Comment: If they have the checkbox checked, at some point call revokeExtendedPermission. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/

Comment: I guess this should do the trick for now as this api is in the process of being deprecated :   We are in the process of deprecating the REST API. If you are building a new Facebook application, please use the Graph API. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, the Graph API is the center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new features will be found.

Answer (score 2):

> You can de-authorize an application entirely, or just revoke a
>   specific permission on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE to
>   PROFILE_ID/permissions or PROFILE_ID/permissions/PERMISSION_NAME
>   respectively. This request must be made with a value user access_token
>   for the current app.
>
> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

i.e. revoke email permission:  Post DELETE to https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions/email

Using the REST API (legacy) you can do it in the frontend:

```
FB.api({method:'auth.revokeExtendedPermission', perm:'user_photos'});
```

You can then ask for permissions again (FB.Login) and it will prompt them for the permission.